# datatable stuck in Cannot read property length of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I have been trying to use jquery Datatable to display response from an API. I have tested it will HTML table and it displays fine. But the page is too long so I need to use a table with pagination.

I got Datatable plugin. I have implemented what I saw, did a lot of googling and here on StackOverflow but no head way yet.

I dont know what I am doing wrong

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var Id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

  debugger
    jQuery('#ppViewHistoryPage').DataTable( {
        "ajaxSource": 'https://api.premiumpension.com/multichannel/api/Prices/GetFundPriceByDateRange?fundId='+Id+'&startDate=2014-1-1&endDate=2050-1-1',
       "columns": [
            { "result": "FundName" },
            { "result": "ValueDate" },
            { "result": "UnitPrice" },
        ]


    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it
For those that might be having the same problem

The dataSrc is your array result. 
the pass  {"data": "nameofField"},

data is compulsory here. I was until I added data that the table started showing

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var url = window.location.href;
  var Id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

    jQuery('#ppViewHistoryPage').DataTable( {
      ajax: {
          url: 'https://api.premiumpension.com/multichannel/api/Prices/GetFundPriceByDateRange?fundId='+Id+'&startDate=2014-1-1&endDate=2050-1-1',
          dataSrc: 'result'
      },
      "columns": [
    {"data": "FundName"},
    {"data": "ValueDate"},
    {"data": "UnitPrice"},
  ]
  });

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#dataTables_show_list").dataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200],
            [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200]
        ],
        "bFilter": false,
        "columns": columns,
        "order": [
            [0, "asc"]
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "orderable": false
        }],
        "ajax": {
            url: 'https://api.premiumpension.com/multichannel/api/Prices/GetFundPriceByDateRange?fundId='+Id+'&startDate=2014-1-1&endDate=2050-1-1',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'info': dataInfo
            }

        },
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        "searching": true,
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
        ]
    });
```

Response from ajax will be something like

```
[["Md. Belal Uddin","SSD-TECH Head Office","01717255982","active","2017-01-15 14:41:07","<span class=\"edit_contactnumber\"><a class=\"text-decor\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"managerManager('edit',20)\">Edit<\/a><\/span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"edit_contactnumber\"><a class=\"text-decor\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"getAllManagerAccount(20)\">List Customer<\/a><\/span>"],["Md. Rakibul Hasan Chowdhury","SSD-TECH","01799994853","active","2018-06-07 12:24:59","<span class=\"edit_contactnumber\"><a class=\"text-decor\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"managerManager('edit',429)\">Edit<\/a><\/span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"edit_contactnumber\"><a class=\"text-decor\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"getAllManagerAccount(429)\">List Customer<\/a><\/span>"],["Tarique Haider","SSD-TECH","453453534","active","2017-01-05 19:37:21","<span class=\"edit_contactnumber\"><a class=\"text-decor\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"managerManager('edit',7)\">Edit<\/a><\/span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"edit_contactnumber\"><a class=\"text-decor\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"getAllManagerAccount(7)\">List Customer<\/a><\/span>"]]
```